# Tree View Messageboard - disable submit button not working for children

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, treeview, parent-child

CORRECTIONS MADE BELOW..

I have a message board (like a conversation tree) that has parent messages and child messages. I have implemented the jquery below that disables the submit button when nothing is typed in the input box. It works on the parent submit button (#sendcomment input box) but not on the children (also #sendcomment input box).  Any ideas?

```
<div id="defaultcontainerwrapper" class="maxwidth">
    <div class="messageList" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:30px;">
            <?php foreach($this->messageList as $k=>$message){
                $postId=$message['postId'];
                if($message['depth']!=0){
                    $depth=$message['depth'];
                    do{
                        echo(": . . ");
                        $depth--;
                    }
                    while($depth!=0);
                }
                ?>

        <span class="viewThread">
            <a style="color:#cd6b2e;text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; cursor: hand;"
               onclick="<?php echo "javascript:ajaxView(" . $postId . ");"; ?>"><?php echo $message['content'] ? nl2br(substr($message['content'], 0, 30)) . '...' : ''; ?></a>
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars("<");?><a style="color:grey;"><?php echo $message['posterName'];?></a><?php echo htmlspecialchars(">")."&nbsp".$message['date']."<br/>\n";?>
        </span>

                <div class="displayPanel" id="<?php echo $postId;?>" >
                    <div class="displayContent" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="RepForm-loggedin" >
                        <form name="RepForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->newReply;?>">
                            <table name="RepFormTable" style="width:100%">
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="data/js/jquery_lib/jquery.min.js"></script>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100%">
                                        <input type="text" maxlength="75" id="repContent" class="inputbox inputbox-title placeholder-soc-med"
                                               name="repContent" placeholder="Add your comment here. . ."/>
                                        <span><input type="submit" id="sendComment" name="sendComment" class="dgrey-button cancel-button" value="Submit"></span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <textarea style="display: none" name="content"></textarea>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->tag ;?>" name="tag">
                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="parentId">
                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="depth">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sendComment = document.getElementsByName("sendComment");
    var repContent = document.getElementsByName("repContent");
    $(sendComment).attr('disabled', true);
    $(repContent).keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length != 0)
            $(sendComment).attr('disabled', false);
        else
            $(sendComment).attr('disabled', true);
    })

});

<script>
```

Comment: Could be a problem reusing the id #sendComment.  id attributes are meant to be unique per page

Comment: Thank you, @RyanTuosto. That solved the problem.

Comment: @RyanTuosto My solution was to add name="sendComment" to the input.  Then I used document.getElementsByName("sendComment") to reference the name.  Worked like a charm. Corrections made above.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

If you want you could append the parent message id such as `id="sendComment-<?php echo $postId; ?>"` then use the selector `$("[id*=sendComment]")` to query all elements whose ids contain "sendComment"